# how to handle resource versioning for a collection response

Tags: rest, http, http-headers

I'm trying to implement some concurrency in a rest service using ETag header for specifying the resource version and If-Match to control updates.

In some cases a collection of resources need to be returned in a single get response. I want to still allow for an item from the collection to be modified and sent within an update request. My question is when returning this collection are there any best practices for providing the resource version? An array as the ETag value? In the response body is the only practical thing I've come up with so far.